# Accessing a struct causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting a segmentation fault when I go to access the struct `vm`? The code is as follows:

```
BOOLEAN vm_init(struct vm * vm)
{
    struct vm_node * vmNode;
    vmNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    vm->item_list->head = vmNode;
    vm->coinsfile = " ";
    vm->foodfile = " ";
    return FALSE;
}

/* 
 * Loads data from the .dat files into memory. 
 * */
BOOLEAN load_data(struct vm * vm, const char * item_fname, 
                  const char * coins_fname) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(item_fname, "r+");
    char buf[256]={};
    struct vm_node *vmNode;
    vmNode = malloc(sizeof(struct vm_node));
    vmNode->next = NULL;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
        addNodeBottom(buf,vmNode);
    }

    /* Test reason for reaching NULL. */
    if (feof(file)) /* if failure caused by end-of-file condition */
    {
    }
    else if (ferror(file)) /* if failure caused by some other error      */
    {
        perror("fgets()");
        fprintf(stderr, "fgets() failed in file %s at line # %d\n", __FILE__,
                __LINE__ - 9);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(file);
```

If I try to access `vm->item_list->head` it segfaults. `item_list` is the container to a linked list, which is what `vmNode` is. So i need to store `vmNode` within `vm->item_list->head`.

But if I do the following:

```
vm->item_list->head = vmNode; //it segfaults...
```

Any clues?

The typedefs for vm and vm_node are as follows.

```
struct stock_item
{
    char id[IDLEN+1];
    char name[NAMELEN+1];
    char description[DESCLEN+1];
    struct price price;
    unsigned on_hand;
};

/* The data structure that holds a pointer to the stock_item data and a
 * pointer to the next node in the list
 */
struct vm_node
{
    struct stock_item * data;
    struct vm_node * next;
};

/* The head of the list - has a pointer to the rest of the list and a 
 * stores the length of the list 
 */
struct vm_list
{
    struct vm_node * head;
    unsigned length;
};

/* This is the head of our overall data structure. We have a pointer to 
 * the vending machine list as well as an array of coins. 
 */
struct vm
{
    struct vm_list * item_list;
    struct coin coins[NUMDENOMS];
    char * foodfile;
    char * coinsfile;
};
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown is `item_list` assigned to anything other than null.  How is this initialized?

Comment: @dbc i changed it so that it is now initialised to a an empty vm_node struct.

Comment: @JoshuaTheeuf Use a debugger to find out where you are receiving the Segmentation fault.

Comment: Where are you assigning memory to struct vm? Without assigning memory you are trying to write some value to elements in the struct vm

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown do you allocate a `struct vm_list` and assign it to `item_list`.  Since `malloc` does not fill memory with zeros, `vm->item_list` is an uninitialized pointer.  Debug it and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This is the head of our overall data structure. We have a pointer to 
 * the vending machine list as well as an array of coins. 
 */
struct vm
{
    struct vm_list item_list;
    struct coin coins[NUMDENOMS];
    char * foodfile;
    char * coinsfile;
};
```

One little fix. The `item_list` is just a pointer and an int.
This allocates the memory for it within the `struct vm`
You had the pointer but not the structure it should be pointing to.

You will now have to use

```
vm.item_list->head = vmNode;
```

when setting the initial node.

And that should solve your problem.